# display_errors set to On but shows Off in phpinfo()

Tags: apache, php

I'm on OS X 10.9 (though, it was the same in 10.8)

I'm trying to get display_errors set to On but can't figure it out.  I didn't have a php.ini file in /etc so I copied /etc/php.ini.default `cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini`.

I then went into /etc/php.ini and uncommented the line `display_errors` and set it to On - `display_errors=On`.  Saved the file and went to `phpinfo()`.

For "Configuration File (php.ini)" Path it shows "/etc" and for "Loaded Configuration File" it shows "/etc/php.ini" so I assume that means it's using the correct php.ini file right?

But, when I scroll down in phpinfo() it shows "display_errors" as Off for both Local Value and Master Value.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there another place I need to turn display_errors On?  I'm using PHP 5.4.17

Edit: Forgot to mention that I've restarted apache several times with `sudo apachectl restart` and still no change.

Also, I found it weird that before I copied php.ini.default to /etc/php.ini, php was presumably using some default php.ini file but display_errors was still set to Off.  Isn't that On by default?

Comment: Have you restarted apache?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have put that in there.  I've restarted apache several times.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have two lines (one that says Off and one that says On?)

Comment: In phpinfo, it should say where the configuration is being loaded from.  Or, you can use the function `php_ini_loaded_file` to get the path.  Is it pointing where you're expecting it to?

Comment: Oh geez...I feel stupid.  h2ooooooo was correct, one was set to off later down the page.  I guess I uncommented where it was just explaining values and not where it was actually set.  All good now, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

h2ooooooo got it figured out.  I uncommented the wrong section to set it to On.  It was turing back off later down the page.  All good now.